# How to format numbers with leading spaces in Java

Tags: java, formatting, padding, space

I have the following Java codes to generate numbers padded by zeroes.

```
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("000");
    for (int y=1; y<12; y++)
    {
        System.out.print(fmt.format(y) + " ");
    }
```

The output is as follows:

`001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010 011`

My question is: how do I generate numbers with padded spaces instead of leading zeroes?

`1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11`

Note: I know there are several quesitons achieved in StackOverflow asking for padding spaces in String. I know how to do it with String. I am asking is it possible to format **NUMBERS** with padded space?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
    for (int y=1; y<12; y++)
    {
        System.out.print(String.format("%1$4s", y));
    }
```

It will print Strings of length 4, so if y=1 it will print 3 spaces and 1, **"   1"**, if y is 10 it will print 2 spaces and 10, **"  10"**

[See the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: Why the concatenation?

Comment: I agree with above comment, I think it should be better: String.format("%1$5s", y)

Comment: changed. I was thinking about using a variable

Comment: @Avempace If we do it this way, all numbers (regardless of their length) will receive same amount of space padding.

Comment: No, it will print 4 characters, so 3 spaces if the length of the number is 1 char and 2 if it is 2.

Comment: Your choice of pattern seems overly complex. `%4d` is much easier to read.

Answer (score 16):

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 12) {
    System.out.printf("%4d", i);
    ++i;
}
```

The 4 is the width. You could also replace printf with format.