# In my Java code of an array index, what do I do to format the output of the columns of numbers to line up with each-other?

Tags: java

The code below displays these results:

```
Array Contents:
 175 4 123 53 96 145 181 158 193 154
 85 6 131 60 27 119 79 115 178 98
 68 78 190 178 18 99 8 162 94 105
 169 74 92 134 139 96 64 38 71 111
 189 156 36 49 162 191 39 65 150 193

The largest number is 193 at array index 8
The lowest number is 4 at array index 1
```

The output I want my code to display:

```
Array Contents:
 175   4 123  53  96 145 181 158 193 154
  85   6 131  60  27 119  79 115 178  98
  68  78 190 178  18  99   8 162  94 105
 169  74  92 134 139  96  64  38  71 111
 189 156  36  49 162 191  39  65 150 193

The largest number is 193 at array index 8
The lowest number is 4 at array index 1
```

My code:

```
/*This program generates 50 random numbers between 0 and 200 printing 10
numbers in 10 lines, plus finds the smallest and largest array index*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayOperations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an array of type integer and size 50
        int[] numbers = new int[50];

        // Populate the array with randomly generated numbers between 0 and 199
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 200);
        }

        // Display the array contents in groups of 10 numbers per line
        System.out.println("Array Contents:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + numbers[i]);
            if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println(); // Move to the next line after every 10 numbers
            }
        }

        // Search the array to find the highest and lowest numbers and their location
        int max = numbers[0];
        int min = numbers[0];
        int maxIndex = 0;
        int minIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > max) {
                max = numbers[i];
                maxIndex = i;
            }
            if (numbers[i] < min) {
                min = numbers[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }

        // Display the highest and lowest numbers and their positions in the array
        System.out.println("\nThe largest number is " + max + " at array index " + maxIndex);
        System.out.println("The lowest number is " + min + " at array index " + minIndex);
    }
}
```

I have tried reformatting the line System.out.print(" " + numbers[i]); many times, used the System.out.printf() format only to get a compile error, and even tried System.out.print("/t" + numbers[i]); with spaces and moving the text in the parenthesis around again and again. Nothing came close to what I want. I would be grateful for how someone's assistance, please.

Comment: Replace the space with one or more tabs ```System.out.print("\t" + numbers[i]);```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22541145/6650475) should help get started.  It becomes a little more complicated if for example one of the columns does not have a three digit number and you want to have min space between the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *[printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))* method.
The *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* class *JavaDoc* has a list of *format-specifiers* and other *syntax*.

```java
System.out.printf("%5d", numbers[i]);
```

Output

```
Array Contents:
   16  114   26   59  177   67   61  105    1  190
   22   85  123   42   67   20  189  167   69  175
  194   39  135   28   54    8   68   94  107  134
  194   95   51  172   86   92  181  134  165   92
  118   74   14  179   75   99  183  115  178   55

The largest number is 194 at array index 20
The lowest number is 1 at array index 8
```

Alternately, you may want a dynamic width.
For that, you'll need to first find the value with the most digits.

You can use a *loop*.

```java
int m = String.valueOf(numbers[0]).length();
for (int i = 1, v, n = numbers.length; i < n; i++)
    if ((v = String.valueOf(numbers[i]).length()) > m)
        m = v;
```

Or, a *stream*.

```java
int m = IntStream.of(numbers)
                 .map(x -> String.valueOf(x).length())
                 .max()
                 .getAsInt();
```

Then, build the *format* string.
I'm using *+1* to create a space between the values.

```java
System.out.printf(("%" + (m + 1) + "d"), numbers[i]);
```

Here is a re-factor.

```java
String s;
// Create an array of type integer and size 50
// Populate the array with randomly generated numbers between 0 and 199
int i, v, numbers[] = new Random().ints(50, 0, 200).toArray(),
    n = numbers.length;

// Display the array contents in groups of 10 numbers per line
System.out.println("Array Contents:");
int m = String.valueOf(numbers[0]).length();
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if ((v = String.valueOf(numbers[i]).length()) > m) m = v;
s = "%" + (m + 1) + "d";
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.printf(s, numbers[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
        System.out.println(); // Move to the next line after every 10 numbers
}

// Search the array to find the highest and lowest numbers and their location
int max = numbers[0], min = numbers[0], maxIndex = 0, minIndex = 0;

for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if (numbers[i] > max) max = numbers[maxIndex = i];
    else if (numbers[i] < min) min = numbers[minIndex = i];

// Display the highest and lowest numbers and their positions in the array
System.out.println("\nThe largest number is " + max + " at array index " + maxIndex);
System.out.println("The lowest number is " + min + " at array index " + minIndex);
```

Comment: @RaleighBrecht  Then you should accept and even upvote the answer.   Upvoting says the answer(s) were helpful.  Accepting says this was the best one (in your opinion).  It also rewards the answerer(s), gives you two points of rep, and allows the answer to be easily searched for future related questions.

Comment: Or `.map(String::valueOf).map(String::length)`.